# linux zoneminder video with striped black and white lines

Tags: linux, linux-device-driver

I'm totally new to zoneminder and linux it self (so I have no idea at all with what to start in my problem). Somehow I managed to install zoneminder and added one camera (monitor), but when I try to view it, it's showing striped black and white screen or sometimes totally black screen:

[image]

I have Ubuntu 12.10; ZoneMinder: v1.25.0;
Video capturing card works as 4 separated video channels: /dev/video[0 to 3]

When runing `lspci` in terminal, it shows that the card is: `Philips Semiconductors SAA7134/SAA7135HL Video Broadcast Decoder`.
Bought the card from dealextreme: [goo.gl/ddSx4](http://goo.gl/ddSx4)

Settings for zoneminder monitor:
**General**
Source Type: local
Function: monitor
Enabled: [true]
Maximum FPS: 25.00
Reference Image Blend %ge: 7

**Source**
Device Path: /dev/video3, - also tried with video0, video1, video2
Capture Method: Video for linux version 2
Device Channel: 0
Device Format: PAL (tried also with NTSC) 
Capture Palette: YUYV
Capture Width (pixels): 320
Capture Height (pixels): 240

I have not changed anything else.

Also there is no difference if there is cameras plugged in or not, the same striped screen or sometimes totally black screen shows up.

Can someone please help me with this problem? What this could be? Is the card broken or drivers, or is this some problem with `zoneminder` configuration?
I have no idea with what to start to fix this problem, could someone please help? If possible in some "zoneminder/linux for dummies" way. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Unbelievably I fixed this.
Here`s the solution:

What I did is:
1) Opened for editing file (as root user): `/etc/modprobe.d/saa7134.conf`
2) Added this line at the end of file:
`options saa7134 card=33,33,33,33`
3) saved and restarted computer.

And that's it, it works now.